# Is there a way to change my home folder to encrypted after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: encryption, home-directory

I somehow missed the option to encrypt my home folder when upgrading to 12.04. It was not encrypted in 11.10. How might I do so without a re-installation? Or can I? I'm fairly new to Ubuntu so please dumb it down for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great tutorial. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/encrypt-home-folder-ubuntu-installation-linux/ It was written for 11.10, but it should be more or less the same.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at it and see if I have any more questions.